# Amazon SP-API SDK

Tags: laravel, upload, amazon-selling-partner-api

can someone explain me how to create and upload xml file on AWS as Feed. I tried https://github.com/amazon-php/sp-api-sdk/blob/5.x/src/AmazonPHP/SellingPartner/Api/FeedsApi/FeedsSDK.php#L225  and https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/feeds-api-v2021-06-30-use-case-guide, but every time I am getting url and feedDocumentId, but when I try to upload it on that url, I am getting on url this:

```
<Error>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
<AWSAccessKeyId>AKIAX2ZVOZFBB4YFXXHU</AWSAccessKeyId>
<StringToSign>AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 20231106T080142Z 20231106/eu-west-1/s3/aws4_request c2cbc4a511455b617c11d9ea1b41bfd2134b4f7d646b286e7848a9203ef5e13e</StringToSign>
<SignatureProvided>e01f1837a5e5cc2d4defae363a83812b2e48c5b4d9c28fcc46f6a96a9a7d24cf</SignatureProvided>
<StringToSignBytes>41 57 53 34 2d 48 4d 41 43 2d 53 48 41 32 35 36 0a 32 30 32 33 31 31 30 36 54 30 38 30 31 34 32 5a 0a 32 30 32 33 31 31 30 36 2f 65 75 2d 77 65 73 74 2d 31 2f 73 33 2f 61 77 73 34 5f 72 65 71 75 65 73 74 0a 63 32 63 62 63 34 61 35 31 31 34 35 35 62 36 31 37 63 31 31 64 39 65 61 31 62 34 31 62 66 64 32 31 33 34 62 34 66 37 64 36 34 36 62 32 38 36 65 37 38 34 38 61 39 32 30 33 65 66 35 65 31 33 65</StringToSignBytes>
<CanonicalRequest>GET /dc372987-1dd1-43b3-b516-27dc78dca0ec.amzn1.tortuga.4.eu.TH04D1RNGNQZS X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAX2ZVOZFBB4YFXXHU%2F20231106%2Feu-west-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20231106T080142Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=content-type%3Bhost content-type: host:tortuga-prod-eu.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com content-type;host UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD</CanonicalRequest>
<CanonicalRequestBytes>47 45 54 0a 2f 64 63 33 37 32 39 38 37 2d 31 64 64 31 2d 34 33 62 33 2d 62 35 31 36 2d 32 37 64 63 37 38 64 63 61 30 65 63 2e 61 6d 7a 6e 31 2e 74 6f 72 74 75 67 61 2e 34 2e 65 75 2e 54 48 30 34 44 31 52 4e 47 4e 51 5a 53 0a 58 2d 41 6d 7a 2d 41 6c 67 6f 72 69 74 68 6d 3d 41 57 53 34 2d 48 4d 41 43 2d 53 48 41 32 35 36 26 58 2d 41 6d 7a 2d 43 72 65 64 65 6e 74 69 61 6c 3d 41 4b 49 41 58 32 5a 56 4f 5a 46 42 42 34 59 46 58 58 48 55 25 32 46 32 30 32 33 31 31 30 36 25 32 46 65 75 2d 77 65 73 74 2d 31 25 32 46 73 33 25 32 46 61 77 73 34 5f 72 65 71 75 65 73 74 26 58 2d 41 6d 7a 2d 44 61 74 65 3d 32 30 32 33 31 31 30 36 54 30 38 30 31 34 32 5a 26 58 2d 41 6d 7a 2d 45 78 70 69 72 65 73 3d 33 30 30 26 58 2d 41 6d 7a 2d 53 69 67 6e 65 64 48 65 61 64 65 72 73 3d 63 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 74 79 70 65 25 33 42 68 6f 73 74 0a 63 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 74 79 70 65 3a 0a 68 6f 73 74 3a 74 6f 72 74 75 67 61 2d 70 72 6f 64 2d 65 75 2e 73 33 2d 65 75 2d 77 65 73 74 2d 31 2e 61 6d 61 7a 6f 6e 61 77 73 2e 63 6f 6d 0a 0a 63 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 74 79 70 65 3b 68 6f 73 74 0a 55 4e 53 49 47 4e 45 44 2d 50 41 59 4c 4f 41 44</CanonicalRequestBytes>
<RequestId>EJ9N9STNFFT5FT97</RequestId>
<HostId>rVh8aMdyJ3nzfI2vIqgvn0WHCwkfEvZAAMtZ33JY6Bk8OyFNCucBKesfAe3gLyvLjo50ZVsfY223ZyzfEcYp+g==</HostId>
</Error>
```

This is what I am doing, but every time I am getting an error:

```
public function createFeed($distributionChannelTeamId)
    {

        $res=$this->createFeedDocument($distributionChannelTeamId);

        $url=$res['url'];
        $feedDocumentId=$res['feedDocumentId'];


    if($res['url'] && $res['feedDocumentId']){
        $requestXml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
        <AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
          <Header>
            <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
            <MerchantIdentifier>MYID</MerchantIdentifier>
          </Header>
          <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
          <PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace>
          <Message>
            <MessageID>1</MessageID>
            <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
            <Product>
              <SKU>56789</SKU>
              <StandardProductID>
                <Type>ASIN</Type>
                <Value>B0EXAMPLEG</Value>
              </StandardProductID>
              <ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_NOTAX</ProductTaxCode>
              <DescriptionData>
                <Title>Example Product Title</Title>
                <Brand>Example Product Brand</Brand>
                <Description>This is an example product description.</Description>
                <BulletPoint>Example Bullet Point 1</BulletPoint>
                <BulletPoint>Example Bullet Point 2</BulletPoint>
                <MSRP currency="USD">25.19</MSRP>
                <Manufacturer>Example Product Manufacturer</Manufacturer>
                <ItemType>example-item-type</ItemType>
              </DescriptionData>
              <ProductData>
                <Health>
                  <ProductType>
                    <HealthMisc>
                      <Ingredients>Example Ingredients</Ingredients>
                      <Directions>Example Directions</Directions>
                    </HealthMisc>
                  </ProductType>
                </Health>
              </ProductData>
            </Product>
          </Message>
        </AmazonEnvelope>';

        $response = Http::withHeaders(['Content-Type' => 'application/xml'
        ])->put($url,[
            'body' => utf8_encode($requestXml)
        ]);

        Log::channel('amazon')->info('Amazon create feed response: ', ['response' => $response]);
        dd($response);

      }else{
        dump('no res');
        dd($res);
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution for this create product feed in Laravel with Amazon SP-API (https://github.com/amazon-php/sp-api-sdk):

```
composer require amazon-php/sp-api-sdk
composer require nyholm/psr7 -W


use AmazonPHP\SellingPartner\AccessToken;
use AmazonPHP\SellingPartner\Model\Feeds\CreateFeedDocumentSpecification;
use AmazonPHP\SellingPartner\Model\Feeds\CreateFeedSpecification;
use AmazonPHP\SellingPartner\Regions;
use AmazonPHP\SellingPartner\SellingPartnerSDK;
use App\Models\Amazon\AmazonAuth;
use Exception;
use GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use AmazonPHP\SellingPartner\Api\FeedsApi\FeedsSDK;
use AmazonPHP\SellingPartner\Configuration;
use AmazonPHP\SellingPartner\Exception\ApiException;
use AmazonPHP\SellingPartner\Exception\InvalidArgumentException;
use AmazonPHP\SellingPartner\HttpFactory;
use AmazonPHP\SellingPartner\HttpSignatureHeaders;
use AmazonPHP\SellingPartner\ObjectSerializer;
use Psr\Http\Client\ClientExceptionInterface;
use Psr\Http\Client\ClientInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use AmazonPHP\SellingPartner\OAuth;
use Buzz\Client\Curl;
use Nyholm\Psr7\Factory\Psr17Factory;
use Psr\Log\NullLogger;


public function getAccessToken($channelId)
  {

    $amazonAuth = AmazonAuth::where('channel_id', $channelId)->first();  //my local database channel
    $isExpired = Carbon::parse($amazonAuth->expires_at)->isPast();
    $token = null;

    if ($isExpired) {

      $data = [
        'grant_type' => 'refresh_token',
        'refresh_token' => $amazonAuth->refresh_token,
        'client_id' => TenantService::getLwaClientId(),
        'client_secret' => TenantService::getLwaSecret()
      ];

      $response = Http::asForm()->post(
        'https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token',
        $data
      );


      if ($response->successful()) {
        $body = $response->json();
        $amazonAuth->access_token = $body['access_token'];
        $amazonAuth->expires_at = now()->addSeconds($body['expires_in'])->toDateTimeString();
        $amazonAuth->save();

        $token = $body['access_token'];
      } else {
        Log::channel('amazon')->info('Amazon access token refresh failed for amazon auth id: ' . $amazonAuth->id);
       
      }

    } else {
      $token = $amazonAuth->access_token;
    }

    if ($token) {
      $accessToken = new AccessToken(
        $token,
        $amazonAuth->refresh_token,
        'refresh_token',
        (int) $amazonAuth->expires_in,
        'refresh_token'
      );

      return $accessToken;
    }


  }

public function createFeedTest()
  {

    $client = new Client();
    $factory = new Psr17Factory();
    // $httpFactory = new HttpFactory($factory, $factory);
    $region = 'eu';
    $accessToken = $this->getAccessToken(150);
    $logger = new NullLogger();
    $configuration = Configuration::forIAMUser(
      $getLwaClientId,
      $getLwaSecret,
      $getAwsAccessKey,
      $getAwsSecretKey,
    );
    $sdk = SellingPartnerSDK::create($client, $factory, $factory, $configuration, $logger);
    $region = Regions::EUROPE;

    $specification = new CreateFeedDocumentSpecification;
    $feedDoc = $sdk->feeds()->createFeedDocument(
      $accessToken,
      $region,
      $specification->setContentType('text/xml; charset=utf-8')
    );
    $feedDocID = $feedDoc['feed_document_id'];
    $urlFeedUpload = $feedDoc['url'];

    $fileContent = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
            <Header>
              <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
              <MerchantIdentifier>MYMERCHANTTOKEN</MerchantIdentifier>
            </Header>
            <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
            <PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace>
            <Message>
              <MessageID>1</MessageID>
              <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
              <Product>
                <SKU>56789</SKU>
                <StandardProductID>
                  <Type>ASIN</Type>
                  <Value>B0EXAMPLEG</Value>
                </StandardProductID>
                <ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_NOTAX</ProductTaxCode>
                <DescriptionData>
                  <Title>Example Product Title</Title>
                  <Brand>Example Product Brand</Brand>
                  <Description>This is an example product description.</Description>
                  <BulletPoint>Example Bullet Point 1</BulletPoint>
                  <BulletPoint>Example Bullet Point 2</BulletPoint>
                  <MSRP currency="USD">25.19</MSRP>
                  <Manufacturer>Example Product Manufacturer</Manufacturer>
                  <ItemType>example-item-type</ItemType>
                  <CountryOfOrigin>DE</CountryOfOrigin>
                  <UnitCount>1</UnitCount>
                  <PPUCountType>stück</PPUCountType>
                  <IsExpirationDatedProduct>false</IsExpirationDatedProduct>
                </DescriptionData>
                <ProductData>
                  <Health>
                    <ProductType>
                      <HealthMisc>
                        <Ingredients>Example Ingredients</Ingredients>
                        <Directions>Example Directions</Directions>
                      </HealthMisc>
                    </ProductType>
                  </Health>
                </ProductData>
                <IsHeatSensitive>false</IsHeatSensitive>

              </Product>
            </Message>
          </AmazonEnvelope>';

    dump($feedDoc);
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $urlFeedUpload);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_HTTPS);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8'));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_INFILE, fopen('data://text/plain,' . $fileContent, 'r'));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, strlen($fileContent));
    #Only use below option on TEST environment if you have a self-signed certificate!!! On production this can cause security issues
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    dump($response);
    curl_close($curl);
    $specificationNewFeed = new CreateFeedSpecification([
      'feed_type' => 'POST_PRODUCT_DATA',
      'marketplace_ids' => ['A1PA6795UKMFR9'],
      'input_feed_document_id' => $feedDocID

    ]);


    $responseFeed = $sdk->feeds()->createFeed(
      $accessToken,
      $region,
      $specificationNewFeed
    );
    dd($responseFeed);
  }
```